# Properly defining arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I am trying to define an array of unknown size for a float but don't understand how the malloc() function works, can someone show me what it should look like and how it works?

from what enter code hereI understand it should look something like

```
float * input;
input = new float [];
```

but I get error: "input" does not name a type

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you get? You must not be showing the code that generates that error. You're text is talking about `malloc` but you aren't using `malloc` in your example.

Comment: The error indicates that you wrote this code outside of a function. You have to be inside a function to do `input = new float[n];`.  Also it is illegal to omit the size in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you cannot "allocate an array of undeterminate size".
In C/C++ you can only define a pointer to an area of memory (that is the underlying implementation of an array) as you do:

```
float* input;
```

At this point, all you have is a pointer to float type data that points to nothing,
so you cannot "use" the array until you actually allocate memory for it with the new keyword(C++ only):

```
input = new float[1024];
```

Note that you must specify the length of the array you want to allocate,
so you cannot use array of undetermined length.
If you want to use a container-like structure that grows dinamically, consider 
using std::list or std::vector instead.

If you know the size of the array at compile time, you can just define the array statically, without dynamic memory allocation:

```
float input[1024];
```

This way the array will be on the stack instead of being on the heap, and it will be popped in and out as usual variable as the variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

To allocate arrays in C++ use:

```
size_t array_size = 1024 //Or whatever you need
float* input = new float[array_size]

//... Do some things...

delete[] input
```

But since you're using C++, just use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and never worry about deleting any array:

```
std::vector<float> input;
input.push_back(10.2) //Add more things this way, or reserve ahead of time.
```